# Redirecionamento/Mapeamento de Domínio

Tags: html, laravel, redirecionamento, domínio

Não sei se usei os termos corretos na pergunta, mas vou explicar o que preciso.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e neste sistema deve existir perfis de entidades/empresas. Cada uma delas teria seu endereço dentro do sistema.

Ex: `meu-sistema.com.br/empresa/1`

Digamos que uma entidade X tem seu próprio domínio, ex: `entidade-x.com.br`
Como eu faria, para que quando o usuário acesse: `entidade-x.com.br` seja exibido o conteúdo de: `meu-sistema.com.br/empresa/1`, sem que seja através de `iframe` ou simples redirecionamento.

Na barra de endereços continuaria `entidade-x.com.br`, mas exibindo o conteúdo de `meu-sistema.com.br/empresa/1`.

Se isto é possível, como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, primeiramente você precisa ter um dominio que seria `meu-sistema.com.br` com os direcionamentos do tipo `/empresa/1` funcionando normalmente.

Uma vez isto pronto, você pode criar *canonical names* (ou CNAMES) para seu site, ou seja, um dominio `dominio1.com.br` com CNAME `empresa1.com.br` vão levar ao mesmo lugar e o endereço vai continuar sendo `dominio1.com.br`, ou seja, isto **não é um redirecionamento**, é uma informação do DNS dizendo que este domínio é **não só, mas também** um nome do domínio original.

Atualmente existem diversos provedores que suportam CNAMES, dependendo de onde você está hospedando seu site, a configuração pode ser diferente.